# RecyclerView no se actualiza

Tags: android, recyclerview

Estoy programando una app y tengo un problema con un *recyclerView* que no consigo que se actualice al modificar los datos de la lista. He probado con `.notifyDataSetChanged();` con `miRecycler.setAdapter(adaptador);` pero no hay forma.

La lista de datos se actualiza a partir de una consulta con *Realm* y con *debug* he podido confirmar que la lista se modifica pero el *recycler* no se actualiza.

Este es el código:

```
public class CalendariFragment extends Fragment {

    public CalendariFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private RecyclerView llistaClasses;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RealmResults<Agenda> agenda;
    private AdaptadorAgenda adaptadorAgenda;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendari, container, false);

        /* starts before 1 month from now */
        Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);

        /* ends after 1 month from now */
        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);

        HorizontalCalendar horizontalCalendar = new HorizontalCalendar.Builder(view, R.id.calendarView)
                .range(startDate, endDate)
                .datesNumberOnScreen(5)
                .build();

        Calendar dataAvui = Calendar.getInstance();
        int diaSetmana = dataAvui.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        agenda = realm.where(Agenda.class)
                .equalTo("diaSetmana",2)
                .findAll();

        llistaClasses = view.findViewById(R.id.llistatClasses);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        //Adaptador
        adaptadorAgenda = new AdaptadorAgenda(agenda, R.layout.post_agenda, (name, position) -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), "name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());

        //Aplicar llista a l'adaptador
        llistaClasses.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        llistaClasses.setAdapter(adaptadorAgenda);

        //Aplicar codi per seleccionar una classe
        llistaClasses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        horizontalCalendar.setCalendarListener(new HorizontalCalendarListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(Calendar date, int position) {

                int diaSetmana = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                agenda = realm.where(Agenda.class)
                        .equalTo("diaSetmana", diaSetmana)
                        .findAll();

                adaptadorAgenda.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de porque no funciona?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: @israel-icm gracias por la edición!

Comment: Si no me equivoco, el motivo por el que no se actualiza es que estás *cambiando* la lista. El adapter está *mirando* los cambios en la lista, para ello usa la ***referencia (puntero)*** de la lista que le pasas, el problema es que tú luego haces que agenda sea igual a otra lista que te devuelve realm, con lo cual estás reasignando la lista, pero el adapter sigue mirando la referencia anterior... prueba a cambiar `agenda = realm...` por `agenda.addAll(realm...);` Si quieres *eliminar* lo que ya había, puedes usar `agenda.clear()` antes del `addAll`. A ver si eso lo soluciona :)

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B pero agenda.addAll y agenda.clear me los marca como deprecated. Como puedo reformular mi código? Soy bastante novato...

Comment: Hmmm, nunca había usado Realm antes, parece que la costumbre con realm es *crear un nuevo adapter* cuando hay cambios, y setear el nuevo adapter, por lo visto. No tengo mucha idea, en cuanto al uso de esa librería, pero seguro que en su documentación encontrarás más información al respecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues me respondo a mi mismo ;)

El código que me ha funcionado lo he encontado [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64214158/recycler-view-not-updating-data-with-realm-data) y basicamente se trata de crear un metodo para actualizar la consulta de Realm en el mismo adaptador. Tal y como tu comentavas @Benito-B, gracias, estava actualizando otra lista y no la que cargava el RecyclerView. Dejo el código por si puede ayudar a alguien que se encuentre en la misma situación.

```
   public void updateData(RealmResults<Person> personList) {
       this.persons = personList;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```